# error: file `/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-54-generic` not found

Tags: kernel

When i restart Ubuntu, i cannot log in, an error like this appears:

```
error: file `/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-54-generic` not found
error: you need to load the kernel first
Press any key to continue...
```

How can i restore normal boot?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit grub settings many times but it is useless, tried to remove unnecessary kernels,
but that didn't help either. The only way to restore normal kernel boot is to use:

- need to go to GRUB: Advanced options and select from the list the kernel that is able to boot.
- then go in, update the system and reboot:

`# apt update -y ; apt upgrade -y ; apt dist-upgrade -y ; passwd -dl root ; reboot`

after that i system boots normally.